# Json decoded but no arrays specified

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am pulling a json from a website and using the json_decode function to put it into array's. However the arrays are not being defined so i cannot grab the defined indexes below the first array.

Here is a sample of my json after running through the decode.

```
    Array
    (
        [username] => username
        [confirmed] => 0.00
        [estimate] => 0.00
        [total] => 0000
        [history] => 0000.0000
        [round] => 0000
        [workers] => Array
            (
                [username.1] => Array
                    (
                        [alive] => 1
                        [rate] => 0000
                    )
```

Here is the code i use to get that.

```
    $json = file_get_contents("http://imareal.website", true); //getting the file content
    $decode = json_decode($json, true);
```

So i can access anything in the top most array with

```
    echo "Username: " .$decode["username"];
```

but once i need to go lower then the [workers] it fails to find the index.

Is there any way to define the arrays during or after the decode? Or can i tell it to look lower somehow?

Update:
Okay so running var_dump($decode['workers']);
Gives me:

```
    array(5) { ["username.1"]=> array(2) { ["alive"]=> string(1) "1" ["rate"]=> string(4) "0000" } ["username.2"]=> array(2) { ["alive"]=> string(1) "1" ["rate"]=> string(4) "0000" } ["username.3"]=> array(2) { ["alive"]=> string(1) "1" ["rate"]=> string(3) "0000" } ["username.10"]=> array(2) { ["alive"]=> string(1) "0" ["rate"]=> string(1) "0000" } ["username.11"]=> array(2) { ["alive"]=> string(1) "1" ["rate"]=> string(3) "643" } }
```

When i try using any of the below lines i get an illegal or undefined offset or undefined index.

```
    echo $decode[5]->alive->value;
    echo $decode[2]->alive->value;
    echo "Username.1: " .$decode["username.1"]["alive"];
    echo "Username.1: " .$decode["2"]["alive"];
    echo "Username.1: " .$decode["5"]["alive"];
```

Comment: What are you doing to attempt to grab information 'lower' than workers?

Comment: `foreach($decode['workers'] as $k=>$v){ ...}`

Comment: you have to var_dump($decode['workers']) not echo, since it is not a string. You have to loop through workers if you want to access any of its elements.

Comment: How are you accessing workers? `$decode['workers']['username.1']`?

Comment: i am attempting to access the username.1 alive and rate fields using the same echo method. Also, there is 4 username.1's in number succession, so username.1,username.2,username.3,username.4 all with different alive and rate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo $decode['workers']['username.1']['alive'];
```

If you want the `username.1` then:

```
foreach($decode['workers'] as $worker => $values) {
    echo "username: $worker alive: {$values['alive']}";
}
```